# Choosing loss function in Keras for prediction binary_crossentropy or categorical_crossentropy

Tags: keras, predictive-modeling, lstm, prediction, loss-function

What loss function in keras should I chose for binary_crossentropy or categorical_crossentropy?

I have data like : $w1,w2,w3,w2,w2,w1,w3,w5,w9,w5,w4...$

I want to predict sequence:

input: $w1,w2,w3$  -> $LSTM$ -> get output: $w2,w2,w1$

I encoded the symbols $w1,w2...$ by `obe-hot-encoding`

So the input of the model is : $[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]$

The output of the model is : $[[0,1,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]$

Comment: You are using multiple outputs/classes which needs `categorical_crossentropy`. Also, elaborate your question with some information in order to receive proper guidance.

Comment: You can't predict a **sequence** with ML.  You can predict a *time series*, but a time series requires at least a good handful of features per point in the series. (P.S. the mathematical meaning of sequence vs. series is analogous - although not exactly the same - the difference between your data and a series that ML could be capable of predicting)